# How do I ascend a +10 normal weapon to a +11 normal weapon?

Tags: dark-souls

I know the Large Ember will ascend a +5 normal weapon to a +6 normal weapon, however I'm uncertain how to ascend a +10 normal weapon to a +11 normal weapon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the [Very Large Ember](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/very-large-ember), which can be found in New Londo after you drain the water covering the lower levels. It's located in a chest at the top of some stairs, which are accessible through the first castle building. Once you get it, you simply need to give it to blacksmith Andrei. For a better description of the location, here is a video: